# Force webpage to completely re-render upon screen rotation

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I am building a website with scrollify (forced scroll points) and am in the process of removing landscape orientation from mobile devices (displays only a warning while in landscape) and then returns to normal view and functionality when returning to portrait orientation.

The change in orientation forces a zoom to happen that I cannot seem to be able to resolve by any java forced page reload functionality or delay. The page reprints correctly if I retype the link, but a refresh will not make it happen. Also replacing the link as displayed in my code below does not force the page to re-print to the orientation either.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.onorientationchange = function() { 
        var orientation = window.orientation; 
            switch(orientation) { 
                case 0:
                case 90:
                case -90: setTimeout(()=>{
      window.location.replace("http://www.nebkodo.com/NEBKODO_PRELAUNCH.html")
  },2000)
                 } 
    };
        
    </script>
```

I have also attempted using the `meta content="width=device-width"`

Example site at http://nebkodo.com/NEBKODO_PRELAUNCH.html

Thank you for any help!

Comment: So you just want to reload the page?

Comment: Mobile webkit browsers force content to zoom in when entering into landscape mode and does not zoom out when returning to portrait. So with fixed scoll points the entire design stays zoomed in and out of place ansd essentially breaks. I want it to return to it's original portrait mode "zoomed out" size that it starts at.

Comment: ...so... you just want to reload the page? :) Because that's what you're trying to do here

Comment: When you reload the page it still renders zoomed in with the design broken. It will only re-render the page properlly by physically visiting the link again via address bar., As I stated reloading with ```location.reload```  and ```location.replace``` retain a broken design when reloading.

Comment: What [meta viewport tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) do you use?

Comment: ```<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no" />```

Comment: What about `<meta content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">`

Comment: So, I am able to accomplish a somewhat desired result when using this method - I use a scale of 0.45 for the mobile version to best suit portrait - but when I rotate back to portrait I get strange margins on the sides? Again, this issue only renders in mobile chrome as of now.